# How to solve problem with left join in Hive

Tags: sql, join, hive

Maybe someone knows an answer to following issue with left join in Hive.

1.Let's say i have:

```
table A.c1  table A.c2        table B.c1  table B.c2  table B.c3

2021-05     1701              2021-05     1701        May 5
2021-06     1701              2021-06     1701        June 7
2021-07     1701
```

2.When i go with script like

```
select table A.* , table B.c3 
from table A left join table B 
on table A.c1 = table B.c1 and table A.c2 = table B.c2
```

3.Hive will return with

```
table C.c1  table C.c2 table C.c3
2021-05     1701       May 5
2021-06     1701       June 7
```

4.But i want to get somehow this result(as i remember 'left join' works that way in MS SQL)

```
table C.c1  table C.c2 table C.c3
2021-05     1701       May 5
2021-06     1701       June 7
2021-07     1701       NULL
```

Is my script correct or it is not that simple to do such result?

Comment: Nothing of the sort.  LEFT JOIN in Hive will produce result as expected (your last dataset). Maybe you have something else in your query which transforms it into INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try using right join since the right table doesn't have the criteria met in left table.

```
select table A.* , table B.c3 
from table A right outer join table B 
on table A.c1 = table B.c1 and table A.c2 = table B.c2
```

The HiveQL RIGHT OUTER JOIN returns all the rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table

Comment: Sure, right outer join will return all rows from right table but it won't help because of empty row in left table